# ClearCase plugin for Jenkins - branches with regular expression

Tags: regex, random, jenkins, branch, clearcase

is it possible to set 'Branch(es)' field in ClearCase plugin for Jenkins to monitor randomly changing branches?

I would like to trigger builds when changes appaers on branches whose names are starting with `template` and after that you are randomly set of numbers, for example:

```
template0112121
template1291212
template1231232
```

I know that this case is outsized, but there is connected to my complicated environment. It will be fantastic if it would be possible to set in the filed sth like `template*`.

Has anyone have some kind of hint?

Regards,
Arek

Answer (score 1):

The [ClearCase plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+Plugin) does not show any `<pattern|wildcard|template>` feature regarding the name of the branch monitored.

One workaround would be to use a view configured to select multiple branches, but:

- the [`version_selector`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8m0r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc%2Ftopics%2Fversion_selector.htm) does not include wildcard in the branch name
- even if you list all branches, the view would select only the version present on the first branch (in order listed in the config spec)

So that wouldn't work either.

Considering:

- the Jenkins plugin uses, for change detection, a ClearCase view
- a ClearCase view can only monitor, for a given file, one branch

your case doesn't seem to be supported at the moment.